# Google Maps API keys with Google Dart

Tags: google-maps, dart, api-key

I'm relatively new to this so I apologise if this is worded incorrectly. I'm creating a web application with Google Maps using Dart and have obtained a Google API key, Client ID and Client secret but I am not sure how to link it to my Dart project. For example there is no where in the project itself with this information and I am not sure where it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the steps describe at [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). Once your API key retrieved you only have to add the following *script* (see [Loading the Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)) to your page to start using the API :

```html
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
```

You can look at [this simple example](https://github.com/a14n/dart-google-maps/tree/master/example/01-basics/map-simple) that shows how to use *Google Maps* with *Dart*.

Comment: I've followed the steps at Getting Started as far as I can see and added the script you provided however when I run my project Chromium still says Google API keys are missing before giving me this error: Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key. Really not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: The map now loads as it turns out I hadn't given my map canvas a height. However when Chromium opens it still says Google API keys are missing?

Comment: What do you mean the map loads? How do you know if you are getting that error? I am getting the same error, and in all of the examples I've seen they don't even use a key...I am confused.